# How can I compare an object to an array with Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I am working with two data sets. One is used to filter the other.  The base dataset is a set of folders using a naming scheme like this:

```
003
003 rev 1
003 rev 2
004
005
etc...
```

I have a second set of numbers that signify which folders I want to pull from the first set.  I import them using

```
$numSet = Import-Csv $csvLoc | Where {$_.ItemCategory -eq "CatagoryName"} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty "Folder ID"
```

and they looks something like this:

```
C:\>$numSet
003
005
```

So far this is exactly how I want it.  Now what I want to do is, using the `Get-ChildItem` command, import the locations of the folders so that I can work with them.

```
# This is about how I believe I should go about this.
$folderLocationArray = Get-ChildItem -Path $sourceDir | Where {$numSet.Contains($_.Name)}
```

Because I need to check against an array the obvious choice would be `-contains`, except that doesn't allow me to use wildcards, and the `rev #` that comes after some of the file names means that those files don't show up. This is what happens:

```
C:\>$folderLocationArray
003
005
```

I have also tried `-match` and `-like` with the same results.  Instead of an error, the script either sits and acts like it is running, or returns a blank like this:

```
C:\>script.ps1 #This is set up to output $folderLocationArray

C:>
```

I know that the basics are sound, because I can plug in a single number and it works, and even with an array as the input it still returns files, just not the ones with `rev #` in them.

I'm at a loss. How can I use `Get-ChildItem` and filter the array against an array?

Edit:
To clarify.

I have have a list of numbers. I have a bunch of folders. Every folder starts with a number. Some share the same number. I want to know which folders match the list.

Comment: Im not sure what you are asking. Are you just trying to compare 2 arrays and find the same or unique?

Comment: I want filter the folder names by the numbers, so that only the folders that have the number in their name remain.

Comment: So you want all folders that start with a number correct?

Comment: Clarification: If `003` is in the array, do you want the folders `003`, `003 Rev 1` and `003 Rev 2` to be considered "hits"?

Comment: @JeffZeitlin That's right.  All the folders will start with a number. I want only the folders that start with the numbers in the array that I create.

Comment: Are the numbers that you import, and the leading number in the folder name, both the same fixed length?

Comment: Yes, they should always be the same length.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Filter Results based on array

```
@("001","002","023","006") | foreach{Get-ChildItem -Path $path -filter "$_*" -Recurse -Directory}
```

Answer (score 3):

This will use a filter based on an item in the $numset array

```
$numset = @('003', '005')

foreach ($base in $numset) {
    Get-ChildItem -Directory -Recurse -Filter $($base + "*")
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I wasn't able to get this one working, and the one ArcSet put forward has. I will still try this on Monday to double check, thanks!

Comment: @HairyDresden - Ok. The two (2) solutions are basically the same. I added a `-Recurse` to this one which might be why it did not see the directories.